# Probability that a runner arrives before the other

Tags: probability, random-variables

Two athletes arrive at the finish line of a race in moments $X, Y$ independent. The first comes at a casual time $X$ between $16$ and $17$. The second comes at a  casual time $Y$ between $16.15$ and $17$. Find:
$-$ The probability that $X \le Y$
$-$ The probability that $|Y-X|\le 0.15$

**SOLUTION:**
$$X[16;17]$$
$$Y[16.15;17]$$
$$P(X \le Y) = \frac{60\cdot45-\frac{45^2}{2}}{60\cdot45} = \color{red}{0.625}$$
$$P(|X-Y|\le0.15)= \frac{60\cdot45-\frac{30^2}{2}-\frac{45^2}{2}}{60\cdot45} = \color{red}{0.458}$$
The results should be corrected, but i don't understand how he came to the following formulas (this solution is That of Professor), and i'd like to know if there is another method to solve these two questions. Thanks

Comment: Are the distributions $X\&Y$uniform or what does **random moment** and **casual time** mean?

Comment: @mathreadler reading the question, i think that they are uniform

Comment: They look correct to me if we assume that $X$, $Y$ are uniformly distributed and that $16.15$ actually means $16$ minutes and $15$ seconds.

Comment: Then the density functions will be constant and you have two dimensions or variables, $x_1 \& x_2$, what to do then is to find the areas to perform the integration over in this two dimensional space (and to recall from calculus what the integral of a constant is).

Comment: @Leo163 tes they're right, but I don't understand how he obtained these formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first $\mathbb{P}[X\leq Y]$. You know $X\sim\mathcal{U}(16,17)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{U}(16.25,17)$. If the second athlete comes at $y\in[16.25,17]$ ,then $\mathbb{P}[X\leq y]=y-16$. The *pdf* of $Y$ is $1/(3/4)$. Hence $\mathbb{P}[X\leq Y]=\int_{16.25}^{17}(y-16)\frac{1}{3/4}dy$.

Comment: what is the *pdf*?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: ....ohhh gotcha